# TImageList component for Delphi 7 which supports PNG Images

Tags: delphi, vcl

Does anyone know of a component that descends from TImageList and support PNG images, and compatible with Delphi 7?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm using PngComponents It has TPngImageList. Works well for me.

**EDIT**
New link: http://code.google.com/p/cubicexplorer/downloads/detail?name=PngComponents.zip&can=2&q=

Comment: Linas, Johan, do you know any component that deals with png images rotation?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CnPack IDE Wizards](http://www.cnpack.org/index.php?lang=en) which will make your `TImageList` control accepts PNG image format.

[image: Take a look]
Morever, it will make your IDE much more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

I think the [JEDI Visual Component Library](http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org/)'s TJvImageList does all that.

Comment: I don't think it does natively, it will support whatever types the Delphi TImageList supports. I have Delphi 6 and it doesn't support PNGs because D6 doesn't. I believe PNG support was added natively to D2009.